# Send attachment with mail using apps script

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, email-attachments

I'm trying to send an email with an attachment file with Google Apps Script code. This file will get the tag . Does anyone know how to do it ? In the examples there is only code attached files from Google Drive﻿ .

Comment: Apps Script code runs on the server, it can not read a drive on the users computer, . . . if that's what you mean.  You would need to build a user interface with HTML, and have the user upload the file to Drive, then get the file ID, and use that to reference the file, in order to attach it to the email.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for. One of our team members made this code. It allows attachments without Google drive.

```js
//********************************
//GAS
//********************************

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function processForm(formObject) {
  var myFile = formObject.myFile;

  var FileBytes = myFile.getBytes();
  var FileType = myFile.getContentType();
  var FileName = myFile.getName();
  var FileToSend = {
    fileName: FileName,
    content: FileBytes,
    mimeType: FileType
  };
  // Logger.log(FileType);

  var FileBytes2 = [100, 97, 121, 32, 108, 97, 32, 110, 111, 105, 32, 100, 117, 110, 103, 32, 98, 101, 110, 32, 116, 114, 111, 110, 103];
  var FileToSend2 = {
    fileName: 'test222.txt',
    content: FileBytes2,
    mimeType: 'text/plain'
  };
  var FileToSend3 = {
    fileName: 'test333.txt',
    content: 'noi dung ben trong',
    mimeType: 'text/plain'
  };

  GmailApp.sendEmail('youremail@gmail.com', '6 Attachment example', '6 Please see the attached file.', {
    attachments: [FileToSend, FileToSend2, FileToSend3],
    name: '6 Automatic Emailer Script'
  });

  return FileName;
}
```

```html
//******************************************** //HTML //********************************************



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <script>
    // Prevent forms from submitting.
    function preventFormSubmit() {
      var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
      for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
        forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
        });
      }
    }
    window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);

    function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateUrl).processForm(formObject);
    }

    function updateUrl(filename) {
      var div = document.getElementById('output');
      div.innerHTML = filename;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="myFile" type="file" multiple/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
  <div id="output"></div>
</body>

</html>
```